# Get child / parent properties to update when they change from either component in Lit

Tags: javascript, lit

Just trying out Lit, but I can't seem to figure out how to pass references or whatever so that when my property changes in a parent or child, it changes in both of them.

```
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('simple-greeting')
export class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`p { color: blue }`;

  @property() 
  name = 'Somebody';
  
  changeName() {
    this.name = "Changed From Parent";
  }

  render() {
    return html`
        <p>Hello, ${this.name}!</p>
        <button type="button" @click="${this.changeName}">change name from parent</button>
        
        <simple-child name="${this.name}"></simple-child>
    `;
  }
}

@customElement('simple-child')
export class SimpleChild extends LitElement {
  static styles = css`p { color: red }`;

  @property() 
  name = null;
  
  changeName() {
    this.name = "Changed From Child";
  }
  
  render() {
    return html`
        <p>Hello, ${this.name}!</p>
        <button type="button" @click="${this.changeName}">change name from child</button>
    `;
  }
}
```

[Here it is in the Lit playground](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=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-SGVsbG8sICR7dGhpcy5uYW1lfSE8L3A-XG4gICAgICAgIDxidXR0b24gdHlwZT1cImJ1dHRvblwiIEBjbGljaz1cIiR7dGhpcy5jaGFuZ2VOYW1lfVwiPmNoYW5nZSBuYW1lIGZyb20gcGFyZW50PC9idXR0b24-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-XG4gICAgYDtcbiAgfVxufVxuIn0seyJuYW1lIjoiaW5kZXguaHRtbCIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiI8IURPQ1RZUEUgaHRtbD5cbjxoZWFkPlxuICA8c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9XCJtb2R1bGVcIiBzcmM9XCIuL3NpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZy5qc1wiPjwvc2NyaXB0PlxuPC9oZWFkPlxuPGJvZHk-XG4gIDxzaW1wbGUtZ3JlZXRpbmcgbmFtZT1cIldvcmxkXCI-PC9zaW1wbGUtZ3JlZXRpbmc-XG48L2JvZHk-XG4ifSx7Im5hbWUiOiJwYWNrYWdlLmpzb24iLCJjb250ZW50Ijoie1xuICBcImRlcGVuZGVuY2llc1wiOiB7XG4gICAgXCJsaXRcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcIkBsaXQvcmVhY3RpdmUtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4xLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWVsZW1lbnRcIjogXCJeMy4wLjBcIixcbiAgICBcImxpdC1odG1sXCI6IFwiXjIuMC4wXCJcbiAgfVxufSIsImhpZGRlbiI6dHJ1ZX1d)

How do I properly do this so that when either button is clicked, the parent and child both update properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in every component based framework, upwards communication happens via events, downwards communication via properties.

```html
<script type="module">
import {
  LitElement,
  html, css
} from "https://unpkg.com/lit-element/lit-element.js?module";

class SimpleGreeting extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      name: {type: String},
    };
  }
  
  static styles = css`p { color: blue }`;
 
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = 'Somebody';
  }
 
  render() {
    return html`<p>Hello, ${this.name}!</p>
        <button type="button" @click="${this.changeNameParent}">change name from parent</button>
        
        <simple-child name="${this.name}" @name-changed="${this.changeNameChild}"></simple-child>`;
  }
  
  changeNameParent() {
    this.name = "Changed From Parent";
  }
  
  changeNameChild(e) {
    this.name = e.detail.newname;
  }
}

class SimpleChild extends LitElement {
  
  static get properties() {
    return {
      name: {
        type: String,
      }      
    };
  }
  
  static styles = css`p { color: red }`;
 
  changeName() {
    const options = {
        detail: {newname: 'Changed From Child'},
        bubbles: true,
        composed: true
      };
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('name-changed', options));
  }
 
  render() {
    return html`<p>Hello, ${this.name}!</p>
        <button type="button" @click="${this.changeName}">change name from child</button>`;
  }
}

customElements.define("simple-greeting", SimpleGreeting);
customElements.define("simple-child", SimpleChild);
</script>
<simple-greeting name="World"></simple-greeting>
```